# M formula to add missing dates to table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Suppose I have a PowerBI date table, with some dates missing, similar to the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Date         |     quantity     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1/1/2015       |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1/4/2015       |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Is there an M formula that would add the missing date rows (and just put in null for the second column), resulting in a table like below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Date         |     quantity     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1/1/2015       |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1/2/2015       |       null       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1/3/2015       |       null       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      1/4/2015       |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I know this could be accomplished by merging a full [dates] table with my dataset, but that is not an option in my scenario. And I need to do this in M, during query manipulation, and not in DAX.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Base = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"quantity", Int64.Type}}),

// Generate list of dates between Max and Min dates of Table1
DateRange = Table.Group(Base, {}, {{"MinDate", each List.Min([Date]), type date}, {"MaxDate", each List.Max([Date]), type date}}),
StartDate  = DateRange[MinDate]{0},
EndDate = DateRange[MaxDate]{0},
List ={Number.From(StartDate)..Number.From(EndDate)},
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(List, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
FullList = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type date}}),

//Right Anti Join to find dates not in original Table1   
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Base,{"Date"},FullList,{"Column1"},"Table2",JoinKind.RightAnti),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Table2"}),
Extras = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Table2", {"Column1"}, {"Date"}),

Combined = Base & Extras

in Combined
```

Comment: It appears that this query is intended for Excel. I'm working in PowerBI, not in Excel.

Comment: This is just an example setup in Excel using the sample data you listed. In practice the Source would be whatever your own source of data is (and the code is assuming the exact headers you listed in that sample data). Also I did not know you could append tables using &, that's neat.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

I start with a table named Table2 in an Excel worksheet and use it as my source. It looks like this:

[image]

Then, use PowerBI's *Get Data*, then select *All* > *Excel* and the *Connect* button, and navigate to the Excel file that has the table I'm going to use as my source and select it and click *Open*. Then I select Table2 (the name of the table I want to use) from the tables presented for selection, and I click the *Edit* button. This loads Table2 as my source.

The second and third lines in my M code below (Source and Table2_Table) are what is generated from the above steps and gets me to the table and loads it. These will be different for you, based on your source info. Your source path and file info and table names will be different.

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("mypath\myfile.xlsx"), null, true),
Table2_Table = Source{[Item="Table2",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Generate Dates" = List.Generate(()=> Date.From(List.Min(Table2_Table[Date])), each _ <= Date.From(List.Max(Table2_Table[Date])), each Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(_), 1)),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Generate Dates", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Date"}, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Converted to Table",{"Date"},Table2_Table,{"Date"},"Converted to Table",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Converted to Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Converted to Table", {"Quantity"}, {"Quantity"})
in
#"Expanded Converted to Table"
```

I get this table as output:

[image]

Which I can then use in PowerBI. For example, in a table like this:

[image]

P.S. I noticed that when using this in PowerQuery from within Excel only and *not from within PowerBI*, I need to explicitly change the type for the date fields or else the merge won't work right and the Quantity numbers won't appear. So if doing this only from within Excel and not within PowerBI, this code change seems to work:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Generate Dates" = List.Generate(()=> Date.From(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Date])), each _ <= Date.From(List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Date])), each Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(_), 1)),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Generate Dates", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Date"}, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1",{"Date"},#"Changed Type",{"Date"},"Converted to Table",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Converted to Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Converted to Table", {"Quantity"}, {"Quantity"})
in
#"Expanded Converted to Table"
```

Of course, it probably wouldn't hurt to explicitly assign the date types when working within PowerBI as well...just in case.